# How does one differentiate between the logically possible and the impossible?

Tags: logic, principle-of-non-contradiction

The term “married bachelor” seems to be an obvious contradiction. The very definition of bachelor and unmarried are with respect to each other and so it seems nonsensical to talk about a married bachelor.

But what about terms that seem to contradict each other given their implied meanings? For example, what about a “five armed human”? It is not hard to imagine a human with five arms so some might call this logically possible. But one could also argue a five armed human isn’t a human since humans are known to have two arms and thus through implication argue that this is logically impossible. So which is it??

Lastly, how does one differentiate between the logically impossible and meaningless? Isn’t part of what makes something meaningless also what we know to not be possible, such as a five armed human? And yet, clearly “Jr heheh rurjrbr rhrur” seems much “more” meaningless than a five armed human.

This question stemmed from discussions about God where many argue that some of His attributes (such as omni-knowledge and human free will) contradict each other. People have often tried to get away from this contradiction by saying that God attains knowledge from “outside time”. Is this a rightful evasion or meaningless?

Similarly, some physicalists have argued that a purely immaterial cause (I.e. a mind without a body for example) causing physical effects on the world is impossible. If it is, in what sense? Is it metaphysically possible, logically possible but metaphysically impossible, impossible in both senses, meaningless, or what?

Can one “redefine” terms or propose ways of rescuing these potential contradictions with the phrase “married bachelor” as well?

Comment: What is contradictory about "unmarried bachelor"? It's redundant (a bachelor is unmarried [by definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bachelor)), but I don't see a contradiction?

Comment: My Bayesian posterior belief is that "married bachelor" is more likely to be considered contradictory than "unmarried bachelor".  To err is human, to really foul things up requires trying to type things into a computer.

Comment: Meant to say married bachelor. Edited, thanks for the correction @psmears

Comment: @thinkingman: Ah, makes sense now :)

Comment: Is there a definition of a human as having two arms.  Expectations and definitions are not the same thing.

Comment: Language is more complicated than A + B = Meaning of A + Meaning of B. Married Bachelor is only contradictory if you interpret the meaning of a sentence by conjoining the meaning of every word. Married Bachelor could easily mean, someone who is married, but acts like a bachelor-this could happen if they are only married on paper, and don't live/act like a couple. Unless humans are defined as having two hands- there is nothing inherently contradictory about having a 5 handed human. Logically Impossible means it forms a contradiction, meaningless mean's it doesnt mean anything. A = not A

Comment: leads to a contradiction but ~ * > =  & is meaningless because I haven't defined what the symbols mean

Comment: @MichaelCarey: This seems like a good case for the standard definition of consistency. A consistent logic has a model (and vice versa!); that is, there's a homomorphism from the logic's syntax to the model, and we can say that the characteristics of the model provide a semantics. So, with reality as our model, we should expect our logical languages to be consistent, and to have homomorphisms which embody your equation, `meaning(syntax+(A, B)) = meaning+(meaning(A), meaning(B))`. You'd be better off concluding that English is inconsistent!

Comment: May we have better examples, more clearly expressed? Are you comparing logically possible to impossible, or logically impossible?

My search engine agrees, 'married bachelor’ is a logical fallacy only as a mistake… not as a deliberate non sequitur emphasizing how even married, some men continue to live as bachelors - prolly coined by someone like PG Wodehouse somewhen in the 1930s.

I suggest in reality, it’s so hard to imagine a human with five arms, most will dismiss that out of hand.

How do you yourself differentiate between the logically impossible and the merely meaningless?

Answer (score 7):

**Logical impossibility can only be rigorously defined in a formal language,** one built on consistent, well-defined rules, and a limited universe of discourse. In such a language, we can also distinguish easily between something like "A and NOT A" which is impossible-by-definition, and something like "A and NOT" which is meaningless.

For the kind of move you're looking to make, you would have to be able to map first back to a natural language (which would lose the rigorous definitions) and then to the general material world (which doesn't have well-defined members) and from there to the metaphysical world (which has an unlimited universe of discourse).

So your line of argument really falls prey to **false analogy**. You're taking a set of concepts from a highly structured realm and applying them somewhere that's at a significantly far remove, without any guarantee that the relevant characteristics are preserved across the transitions.

Answer (score 5):

This question collects together a number of different, but related issues, so detailed responses to the specific cases are appropriate:-

Take your second paragraph -

> But what about terms that seem to contradict each other given their implied meanings? For example, what about a “five armed human”?

This is a version of the "black swan" case. In such cases, there is always a choice to be made, whether to include the new case within the definition or not. So when black swans or five-armed humans are discovered, the concept can be expanded (as happened in the black swan case), or the new case can be defined as a new concept. The choice does not need to be arbitrary - the decision to include black swans as swans, for me, is perfectly rational. This just shows that definitions do not necessarily cater for all possible variations in advance and decisions sometimes need to be made.

Your third paragraph asks

> ... how does one differentiate between the logically impossible and meaningless? Isn’t part of what makes something meaningless also what we know to not be possible, such as a five armed human? And yet, clearly “Jr heheh rurjrbr rhrur” seems much “more” meaningless than a five armed human.

The difference between the logically impossible and the meaningless is often not well-defined in much philosophical discussion. For me, the difference is that something logically impossible can serve as the premiss in a *reductio ad absurdum* argument, which is undoubtedly meaningful. But letter (or, indeed, word) salads like "Jr heheh rurjrbr rhrur" cannot. There are varieties of nonsense. "'Twas brillig and the slithy toves/ did gyre and gimble in the wabe" is another one. See [Jabberwocky](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/42916/jabberwocky)

Your fourth paragraph asks

> ... many argue that some of His attributes (such as omni-knowledge and human free will) contradict each other. People have often tried to get away from this contradiction by saying that God attains knowledge from “outside time”. Is this a rightful evasion or meaningless?

On the face of it, "outside time" must be a metaphor, since time is not a spatial concept and consequently has no "outside". But the phrase seems to have some sort of meaning in mathematics. In addition, the "timeless present" is a firmly established concept - see, for example, [Timeless present examples](https://forum.english.best/t/what-does-timeless-present-mean/16024). Formal logic often relies on this use. One would have to find out what is meant by "outside time" before proceeding to argue about it. It may well be that the discussion will get bogged down in the preliminaries, but that itself would be a victory of sorts.

Your fifth paragraph is

> Similarly, some physicalists have argued that a purely immaterial cause (I.e. a mind without a body for example) causing physical effects on the world is impossible. If it is, in what sense? Is it metaphysically possible, logically possible but metaphysically impossible, impossible in both senses, meaningless, or what?

This is the classic objection to dualism and seems conclusive to me. But clearly not everyone agrees, and the concept of a "field" in physics is an awkward case. However, if something can cause a physical effect, it is a physical something. So a field counts as physical, but not as material.

Finally, you ask:-

> Can one “redefine” terms or propose ways of rescuing these potential contradictions with the phrase “unmarried bachelor” as well?

It isn't clear what you have in mind here, but if the use of a word can change over time, one couldn't rule out changes in the use of "bachelor" that would change the status of "unmarried bachelor".

Comment: Indeed, “five armed human” if someone was born with a mutation that meant they had five arms (e.g. the fertilised egg partially separated during development), would they be considered not to be human?  We may not have seen such a case, but I suspect most reasonable people would just accommodate them.

Comment: " time is not a spatial concept " is that consistent with Einsteins space-time?

Comment: @Dikran Marsupial. Oh, certainly, I agree with you about this specific case. But we already distinguish between humans and other animals for various reasons, and I don't think one can rule out the possibility that human-like creatures may be discovered in the future and classified as a new species.

Comment: "However, if something can cause a physical effect, it is a physical something." I think the problem here is another problem of definition, "immaterial" and "non-physical" are not the same thing.  For me "immaterial" implies an absence of matter, but does not imply an absence of energy.  So a being existing as energy (c.f. science fiction trope) would be physical but immaterial.

Comment: @LudwgV, indeed it has already happened retrospectively with Neanderthals and H. heidelbergensis (however you spell it), they were "human" in some ways, but not necessarily human in all respects.

Comment: @Dikran Marsupial. Yes, what I said is entirely consistent with space-time. Time in space-time is a dimension addition to the three spatial dimensions.

Comment: I am far from an expert on that, but from what I have read I am not sure that is necessarily the case rather than it being a coherent space where we perceive time as different to space.  But then again, I suppose that would boil down to what spatial is defined to mean.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial I was careful to use "physical" and " material" in exactly the way that you suggest. The concept of a being existing as energy is conceptually problematic. We have well defined ways of isolating distinct material objects within matter. I'm not convinced the same is true of energy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148339/discussion-between-dikran-marsupial-and-ludwig-v).

Comment: I don't see how the black swan case is relevant to the definition of human unless you define human as an exhaustive list of particulars, which nobody does. Accidental features don't need to be explicitly included in an essential definition. It's how our concept of triangle can account for the infinity of possible triangles without going through all of them. If you had only ever seen white triangles, triangularity still wouldn't need to be revised whatsoever upon finding a black triangle. And you already can know for sure that four-sided triangles simply can't ever be found.

Comment: @Mutoh If only there was some way to know what is essential to being human... The point I was after is that cases may turn up that are not catered for in our existing ideas, and there is no way of predicting what they might be.

Comment: @LudwigV there are ways to know, the only real difficulty is the modern prejudice against essentialism in general. More to the point, if you don't know what a human being is, then you don't have a standard by which to determine whether even 2-armed beings are human (and there are plenty ), let alone 5-armed beings should you chance upon one. It's only because you already know what is essential (& conversely what's accidental) to swans that you can recognize a black something you found as a black swan in the first place. This only reinforces that it's not a version of the black swan problem

Comment: @LudwigV to summarize, it would be a version of the black swan problem if OP wanted to know if 5-armed humans exist. Instead he wants to know whether having 5-arms is compatible with being human, only if the answer is positive then we can ask whether they actually exist. Two very different questions.

Answer (score 4):

Part of the problem with the typical examples of the "logically impossible" is that, they employ a natural language and are more about synonyms and antonyms. When a term lacks a univocal definition (that is, one can cleanly list the necessary conditions that are jointly sufficient, say in defining what a "square" is), it becomes a mess trying to say anything about logical necessity or impossibility. Let me apply this to the cases you are concerned with (God and the soul).

Outside of religious revelation, God is an imaginary or conceptual hypothesis. Various attributes about God are usually poorly defined, and so it's easy for someone to point out "contradictions" from thought-experiments. Since God's attributes are poorly defined, its easy for the theist to evade such critiques. Regarding meaning, one would have to clarify what we mean by "meaningless evasions," because the theist surely finds it meaningful. I typically focus on the nature of the argument for God at issue to set the scope of meaning: if it's a first cause argument, then it needs to be *physically* meaningful as defined by physics.

Some physicalists do try to say it's *a priori* false that an immaterial entity can influence a physical system. Again, one can play with "immaterial," while also asking the physicalist to clearly state what counts as meaningless here. A good physicalist will eventually slip into *a posteriori* concerns about conservation of momentum, etc. From there you exit the debate over logical impossibility to what physics could allow.

In short: a lot of this arises over poorly defined terms, and confusing synonyms with tautologies.

Comment: Great answer. What should one do then in evaluating whether or not a purely immaterial being can influence the world for example? The notion of possibility or impossibility makes a remarkable difference. For one, if it is impossible, no amount of evidence in the world can ever make it possible. There must necessarily be a cause that is material for any physical effect in the world. If it is possible, this changes things dramatically.

Comment: I would assume it's on a case-by-case basis, because how someone uses the term 'immaterial' varies from person to person (physics certainly has no use of such a term, so we can't consult them). Any immaterial entity will need some physical attributes to interact with our world (which is fine, since souls experience time) to respect conservation laws. Beyond that, it's messy because at present, physics has no need to posit such things, so there's no clear criteria on which to define "immaterial" with.

Comment: @thinkingman In short: I don’t see how one can prove immaterial causation is a priori false, because in many situations, the limit case of a “pure immaterial” (no physical properties) is not what people are defending. Any decent argument will be empirical and case by case.

Comment: In order to show that something is apriori possible, one must show that it is meaningful. For example, if I said that there is no disproof for “jeirbej”s to exist, you’d ask what “jeirbej” even means. How can one show that a purely immaterial being causing physical effects means anything?

Comment: Meaningful in what sense? That it is intuitive—no, many counter-intuitive phenomena are real. That it can be expressed in English? Well, God and the soul can be defined in an English dictionary. It all depends on the context: an immaterial soul is defined well enough to be a useful word in English. Now, since the context is physical influence, the advocate must define it in terms used by physics to be  meaningful. If one can do that (which almost nobody even tries), then I don't see it as a priori false, even though it's probably empirically false.

Comment: @Hokon how do you know that non-corporeal souls experience time?

Comment: @DikranMarsupial "Know" isn't the right word (personally, I don't think souls exist). Those that posit we have immaterial souls (typically) state that souls experience time, so that's the hypothesis we work with in one of the cases mentioned by the OP.

Comment: @Hokon I am not sure that is the case, Christianity has views of immaterial souls spending an eternity in heaven or in hell, I'm not sure most people 2000 years ago would be able to clearly articulate the difference between that and living outside time in heaven and hell.  I'm pretty sure I can't now!

Comment: @DikranMarsupial In philosophy of mind, we usually go back to Descartes as the archetype of mind-body dualism. He suggests the soul experiences time (while wedded to its body), and in Phil of mind, dualists retain that stance. Issues of the afterlife are another matter (and wouldn't be constrained by physics anymore, since there's no causal interaction between mind and body).

Comment: @Hokon O.K. I wouldn't regard mind and soul to me the same thing, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Good answer. A psychological factor is that "logical (im)possibility" impresses the neophyte with its perceived high prestige - logic being the grand mistress of all thought and all that, so arguments via logic seem to hold a promise of austere inassailability.

Comment: @Deipatrous: It's more that neither dialectic nor rhetoric have a guarantee of invalidating logical claims. A logical proof proceeds by mechanical rewriting of syntax, guided by axiomatic rules; rhetoric is not capable of disturbing the verification process. It's not so much the logic as it is the *formalism*, and logics are the only reasoning system we've found which can be formalized. (This last point is reinforced by categorical logic; a deductive system *is* a category, definitionally, and vice versa.)

Comment: @Corbin It seems to me that "logical possibility" is used outside of formal contexts; for example, in 'The Conscious Mind', David Chalmers gives, as an example of a logical possibility, the stable existence of a cube of uranium-235 1 mile wide, and I suspect his frequent appeal to logical possibility in this book does give his arguments the aura of being indisputable to at least some of the lay readers among his intended readership. (Aside: he actually writes "a (stable) cubic mile of uranium-235", but that is possible in the natural world if it is suitably distributed.)

Answer (score 3):

You ask about logic (in particular in your title) but then stray into physics or physiology. They are not related: What is possible in nature is essentially unknown (even if nature science gives us a pretty good *pragmatic* idea what to actually expect).

Logic impossibility, by comparison, is really easy: You have two statements with clearly defined meanings (of course, the devil here lurks in the detail because we use natural language) and see whether they contradict each other.

- Define human body as having 2 arms
- Have two statements "Is human body" and "has 5 arms": Logically impossible.
- But, instead, have human body with number of arms left unspecified: No contradiction.

More interesting recently are statements like "is a male" and "has a vagina". Here, too, the logician simply asks for the definition of "male" (let's assume they are familiar with vaginas). If the definition of "male" includes "no vagina", then there is a contradiction; if it doesn't, then there isn't. All the squabbles are the result of people assigning different definitions to natural language terms, sometimes even on purpose.

The logician has no part in this; they simply get out the popcorn, lean back and watch until the dust has settled.

Answer (score 2):

When we first learn logic, we just have to use our imagination as to what is logically possible. Later as we learn more, we can replace this naive idea with more concrete concepts from proof theory and formal semantics. This typically involves introducing formal systems of logic, so somewhere along the way, we transition from relying exclusively on natural language to using formal systems.

Once we have a formal logic, we can make the concept of logical possibility more concrete. Proof theory allows us to define the closely related concept of consistency: we cannot prove a contradiction from something. Formal semantics allows us to define the closely related concept of satisfiability: there is at least one interpretation under which it is true. We lose something along the way, because formal systems will never capture all the features of natural language, but we gain the ability to demonstrate that *this* follows from *that* in a way that is so simple even a computer can do it.

Expressions like 'married bachelor' or 'five armed human' are not contradictions in a strict sense. They have to be interpreted in order to know whether they are true or false. Meanings and linguistic conventions are slippery things that change over time and are not really a satisfactory basis for logic. That said, there is a tradition going back to Abelard that allows for a concept of 'material validity'. Some logicians continue to use it. Some logicians speak of analytic consequence or analytic implication.

In practice, with technical terms we tend to delegate their meanings to experts. If some fish were discovered with two tails, we would let biologists decide whether they were a distinct species or a subspecies or a mutant variation. 'Married bachelor' might become a useful term if 'bachelor' came to be used primarily to refer to people who live a particular lifestyle, rather than people who are single.

Whether a sentence is 'meaningless' is harder to judge. Within formal systems this concept takes concrete form by way of well-formed formulas. But given that natural language is much broader, it would be far too restrictive to say a sentence is meaningless just because it cannot be represented as a well-formed formula. If anything, the word 'meaningless' is thrown around far too much. I suspect this is a hangover from the bad old days of logical positivism when the meanings of sentences were identified with their verification conditions.

Concepts like immaterial cause are not logically impossible. Maybe they are physically impossible: it would be a reasonable methodological assumption to suppose so. To think about the universe from a perspective outside time is not unusual. Logicians often state propositions in a kind of 'timeless present'. The concept of eternalism or the block universe model is a respectable way to think about the universe and is common among some theoretical physicists.

Answer (score 1):

Your definitions are not correct.

##### Metaphysics

Metaphysics includes logic, which is necessary for mathematics.

- Logically, *possibility* is just a predicate with no meaning:

`P(a)` means "a is (P)ossible". Meaning is provided by the reader.

- Mathematically, impossibility means p=0, and possibility is p>0.
- Pure language is not enough to define possibilities. At maximum you can express tautologies: *bachelors are single and that is true, which is true, which is also true...*. But in final terms, this is just logic (predicate logic, the first case above).

##### Experience

Empirically, all probabilities follow:

`0<p<1`

that is, nothing is impossible, and nothing is absolutely sure.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148391/discussion-on-answer-by-rodolfoap-how-does-one-differentiate-between-the-logical); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Here "logically impossible" is presumably equivalent to "contradictory", so the opposition is between "impossible" and "contradictory".  In fact, Leibniz makes precisely such a distinction!  Sometimes he qualifies "impossible" by "accidentally impossible" or "accidentally impossible".  He uses this distinction to explain things like negative numbers, imaginary roots, irrationals, and infinitesimals.  All these seem impossible in our world, but do not actually pose any contradiction: numerous fruitful results in mathematics require these tools and are impossible to ignore.  On the other hand, contradictory things like 2+2=5 (Leibniz's example) are absolutely impossible and useless in the practice of natural philosophy (including mathematics).

Sometimes Leibniz speculates concerning possible worlds: while in our world, square root of -1 may be an impossibility, perhaps in other worlds it isn't.  The "possible worlds" theme is more obscure.  At any rate, when Leibniz speaks of infinitesimals as "fictions" he has precisely this in mind: they are only conditionally impossible, but not contradictory.  Elsewhere he makes it clear that his infinitesimals violate Euclid Book V definition 5 (definition 4 in modern editions), which is closely related to the Archimedean property (the latter seems necessarily satisfied in our world, but perhaps not in others...)  This is at any rate the interpretation we have pursued in a number of scholarly ariticles, including [this publication](https://doi.org/10.1080/26375451.2020.1851120) in the British Journal for the History of Mathematics.  Other Leibniz scholars fiercely disagree; see [here](https://u.cs.biu.ac.il/%7Ekatzmik/depictions.html) for a summary of the debate.